# Need to find google form input field id attribute to pass the value through id

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-forms, google-forms-api

I am trying to create one chrome extension for google form autofill, Now I have a google form and I need to pass the values to that google form through id but when I see the id attribute by inspecting it I cannot find the id could you tell me where can I find the id in the given code

```
   <div class="aCsJod oJeWuf"><div class="aXBtI Wic03c"><div class="Xb9hP"><input type="text" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i6" aria-describedby="i7 i8" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="" badinput="false"><div jsname="LwH6nd" class="ndJi5d snByac" aria-hidden="true">Your answer</div></div><div class="i9lrp mIZh1c"></div><div jsname="XmnwAc" class="OabDMe cXrdqd Y2Zypf" style="transform-origin: 243.747px center;"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: There is no id, as is often the case.  You could use class name or specific html attributes, or relative location to select the element via document.querySelector, for example.

Comment: Can you provide more details on your issue and what you are trying to do?